# How to instantiate a class being "annotation processed"?

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, annotation-processing

I am writing an annotation processor and I need to instantiate a class being processed.

I am extracting some documentation based on the class and its annotations, and I'd like to run a method from this class and output the result in the generated documentation.

Unfortunately, when I try to instantiate it I have a `ClassNotFoundException` which seems logical to me as the processing happens before the compilation round.

I am currently writting an xml file that holds the documentation, maybe there is an annotation post-processor or something similar?

Do you have any idea of workaround?

Comment: Can you be more specific about *why* you're trying to instantiate it? You'll never be able to instantiate a class that you're compiling, so maybe a better question is, "How can I do X *without* instantiating these classes?"

Comment: I want to generate an example of the json message that can be generated by the annotated service

Comment: Well, you have access to the fields and their types in your annotation processor (source metadata). You don't have to have explicit values in your example JSON for it to be a good example, so maybe you can just generate a JSON string with that information? Another option might be to use a BCEL to create a class dynamically from the source metadata to use as a temporary place-holder to generate the JSON. It's been a while since I've worked on an annotation processor, so I can't offer much in way of code, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, definitely, we cannot access a class being processed because at the same time it is **being** compiled.

And there is no way to run the annotation processor after the compilation round.

Then I searched in maven and spot the phase: [**process-classes**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

It is executed just after the compilation succeed, so it is perfect for my needs. During this phase I execute a java class that reads the xml file I have generated during the annotation processing. At this point I can access everything !

HIH